# how to get all hotels which comes under 10 km in google map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new in Google map. i have database of places along with latitude and lang.  so i want to know  that when user wants to search hotel in 10 km then all hotels should be highlights in Google map. and all these hotels will come from database . so can anybody tell me that how to search all hotels which comes under 10 km area.  and distance might be increase because it will  be  entered by user like 5 km ,8 km , 10 km.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can load and use [Geomenty Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) from Google and use function computeDistanceBetween() to get the distance from the specific coordinate to the marker.

```
computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, radius?:number) 
`- Returns the distance between two LatLngs`.
```

If the distance is within the radius you should display the hotel marker.